# HTML Image blurry during browser window resize

Tags: css, html

I have a layer with an Image that is placed on top of other elements.

```
 <div style="position:fixed; top:120; left:120; z-index:4"><img src="1.png" height="150" width="150" style="margin-left:50px; margin-top:20px;"></img></div>
```

When i resize my browser window the image get blurry, i don't change the size or anything. When the resizing is completed the pictures goes sharp again.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Please give a working example of the webpage (along with the image). Also, state which browser and OS are you using. I would say that it is working as intended, since it is very CPU consuming to smooth the image in real-time as you resize it. Things get even more complicated if you have HW acceleration enabled (even the driver version can affect the phenomenon).

Comment: Add your width values in percentage instead of using pixels for responsiveness.